# Does Station stay with the Wyld Stallyns?

Tags: bill-and-ted

Station is one cool dude, and the universes most excellent scientist, famed for making the 'good robot us's' (of Bill and Ted). He/they also play a mean set of bongos with the Wyld Stallyns...the question is, how long if at all did Station stay before returning to 'Heaven'?

Comment: There are recent rumors that a *Bill & Ted 3* may happen.  If it does, we may get an answer to this question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Comic Series "[Bill and Ted's Excellent Comic Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_&_Ted%27s_Excellent_Comic_Book)", Station appears repeatedly in the events following their Bogus Journey albeit not as a member of Wyld Stallyns which now consists of Bill, Ted, The babes and Phil (on bass).

[image: Wyld Stallyns]

Never fear, though! He does save the day when Joanna and Elizabeth get kidnapped in issue #5 and he appears in the 'final panel' of issue #12

In answer to your question, he returns to heaven almost immediately but then seems to be able to travel between heaven and Earth (various time periods) whenever the plot requires it.

[image: Final Panel Bill and Ted Comic]